# Scala - recursively print a box of H*V dimensions?

Tags: scala

Hey guys I'm learning scala and want to create command line tetris for learning it.

I want to print a box which receives two parameters and based on those it prints a table so

```
printBox(2, 2)

// Output:
**
**

printBox(3,4)

// Output
****
****
****
```

In where the first argument is the vertical lines, second the column.

I bet I could do this with normal for loops, but wanted to know if its possible using recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a try for recursively to print "*":

```
  @tailrec
  def printBox(i: Int, j: Int): Unit = {
    if (i == 0) return
    print("*" * j)
    println()
    printBox(i - 1, j)
  } 

  printBox(4,6)
```

Output:

```
******
******
******
******
```

Comment: can simplify with `println( "*" * j)`

Comment: this seems better   def printBox(i: Int, j: Int): Unit = {
    if (i == 0) return
    print("*" * j)
    println()
    printBox(i - 1, j)
  } 

printBox(4,5)

Comment: what is the `@tailrec` annotation for?

Comment: The `@tailrec` annotation does _not_ optimize the code. It ensures that the method will not compile if it is not tail-recursive. Tail-recursion is _always_ optimized whether the annotation is there or not.